# What does 'inbound' mean in the lifecycle events in akka?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

In akka, there are some lifecycle events, e.g.

```
final case class AssociatedEvent(
  localAddress: Address,
  remoteAddress: Address,
  inbound: Boolean)
  extends AssociationEvent

final case class DisassociatedEvent(
  localAddress: Address,
  remoteAddress: Address,
  inbound: Boolean)
  extends AssociationEvent
```

What does the `inbound` mean here?

Answer (score 1):

`inbound` references the direction of the transition. If an `AssociatedEvent` is `inbound`, that means `remoteAddress` wanted to connect to `localAddress`, and the local system accepted it, and if it's `!inbound`, *this* system wanted to connect with the remote system (AKA "outbound"), and the remote accepted it.

The same is true of `DisassociatedEvent`: if `inbound`, the remote system has decided to disassociate; if `!inbound`, the local system has decided to disassociate.